# Knowing when list scrolling reaches the bottom

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListActivity which queries a web service for data.  I've implemented a paging system with the web service so only 25 rows get returned at a time.

I'd like my ListActivity to work like so:  When the user scrolls to the bottom of the list, the ListActivity will query the web service for the next page of data.

How can I tell if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the list?

The way I approached it with [`EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) is to have a placeholder `View` -- typically showing some sort of "Loading" indicator -- that triggers the next data fetch.

There are other strategies, though I do not remember the details off the top o' my head.

Comment: Interesting.  If the new View being created is the last View in the list, perform the next search.  I think I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: Excellent.  I have it working with my CursorAdapter.  Thank you very much!